# States do not change when using styled components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to implement a search bar while using the styled-components library for styling. My issue is that the queried value never changes if I used styled-components. This is my code

```
import styled from 'styled-components'
import React, from 'react'

const SearchBar = styled.input`
  margin-top: 35px;
  float: right;
`

class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
  }

  handleNewQuery = () => {
    this.setState({
      query: this.search.value,
    })
    console.log(this.search.value);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder='Search for...'
        ref={input => this.search = input}
        onChange={this.handleNewQuery}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Which only works if I swap SearchBar with input, otherwise the log prints undefined

Comment: Did the answer/explanation help?

Comment: Indeed, I just haven't had time to try it out. Your explanation is very thorough, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The base issue is the the ref that is being created is returning a `StyledComponent`, not an HTML input element. It simply does not have a `value` property. The reason it starts working when you removing the `styled` aspect and simply render an `<input />`, is then the ref is an actual HTML input element with a `value` property. Try logging the ref in the change event to see this with first the styled component then a standard input. Either way I'd try approaching it as a [Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) using `value` property and `event.target.value` instead of attempting to extract the value from a ref.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import './style.css';

const SearchBar = styled.input`
  margin-top: 35px;
  float: right;
`;

class Header extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      query: ''
    };
  }

  handleNewQuery = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      query: e.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SearchBar
          placeholder='Search for...'
          onChange={this.handleNewQuery}
          value={this.state.query}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you absolutely must use a ref with this styled component. You can used the property [innerRef](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/docs/tips-and-tricks.md#refs-to-dom-nodes) which is specific to styled components to access the underlying HTML input element. This would technically give you access the `value` property. Once again though, the best approach would simply be using a controlled component as described above. The below example is using the newer approach to creating [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), but it would depend on your version of React being used.

```
<SearchBar
  placeholder='Search for...'
  onChange={this.handleNewQuery}
  value={this.state.query}
  innerRef={this.search}
/>
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dnqk3r) showing the functionality in action including the `innerRef`.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`SearchBar` should take a `value` prop instead of using a ref to get the value. Something like this:

```
<SearchBar value={this.state.search} ... />
```